# Count only special characters in a string

Tags: java, string

```java
static int countSpecial(String str){
    String str = "#GeeKs01fOr@gEEks07";
    int special = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (!((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' 
    && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')))
            special++;
        }
    return special;
 }
```

I hope this works simply traverse the string and
check if it is not alphabetic or numeric
Surely it will take less time to solve this
question.

Comment: `Surely it will take less time` ... less time to get an answer or less time to run the actual code?

Comment: Hi.  I suspect your question got closed since it's not clear what you're attempting to achieve that your provided code does not do.  Are you hoping for a more terse solution?  Something that's more efficient?  Something more idiomatic?  Something else?  I would suggest editing your question to address this.

Comment: I suppose it depends upon what you consider is a special character: `int len = "#GeeKs01fOr@gEEks07".replaceAll("[^\\p{Punct}]", "").length();` Or just apply the special characters you want to count: `int len = "#GeeKs01fOr@gEEks07".replaceAll("[^@#~$%^&*?]", "").length();`

Comment: @DevilsHnd "check if it is not alphabetic or numeric".  While that doesn't fully address the question (e.g. do non-ASCII letters count), I think it explains what the author means by "special".

Answer (score 2):

Use [isLetterOrDigit](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/character-isletterordigit-in-java-with-examples/)

```java
Character.isLetterOrDigit('J')
```

If you use that, the algorithm gets much more simpler

```java
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) special++;
}
```

Comment: this is not giving same result as code posted in *question*: e.g. `Character.isLetterOrDigit('á')` will return `true`, but `'á'` is considered special by *question*'s code (same for a LOT of other characters) - but not sure what is meant by "*special*" in posted *question*, if it can even be considered a question}

Answer (score 1):

## Code points

The [Answer by urtiaga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73923622/642706) is partially correct. But the `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

Instead, use code point integer numbers when working with individual characters.

To remove characters that are neither letter nor digit:

```
"#GeeKs01fOr@gEEks07"
.codePoints()
.filter( Character :: isLetterOrDigit )
.collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
.toString()
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/SY6PPO).

> GeeKs01fOrgEEks07

To count the characters that are neither letter nor digit:

```
"#GeeKs01fOr@gEEks07"
.codePoints()
.filter( codePoint -> ! Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint ) )
.count()
```

> 2

Answer (score 0):

We could use `String#replaceAll` for a one line solution:

```java
int countSpecial(String str) {
    return str.length() - str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "").length();
}

String str = "#GeeKs01fOr@gEEks07";
System.out.println(countSpecial(str));  // 2
```

Comment: Yea, we could.  But I read the question as asking for a *more efficient* solution ... though it is hard to be sure due to the OP's poor English.